# What should we do about Linguistics.SE questions that are on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

From this [meta question](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1700/question-from-language-learning-how-can-we-best-compliment-this-site) posted on Linguistics.SE by Flimzy, we can see a list of several questions asked there that could definitely be on-topic here. Should we ask to migrate them here? Should we cross-post them? Ignore them?

Answer (score 2):

Whether a question should be migrated depends on two things (in general--not specifically related to these two sites):

1. Is the question on-topic where it was asked?  If not, and only if not...
2. Is the question on-topic somewhere else?

So in a way, us asking if these questions should be migrated is a bit backwards.

We can *offer* to receive such questions. But it's up to Linguistics.SE whether or not the questions also belong on their site. If they are willing to field such questions, they are under no obligation to migrate.

Things as they are, I would suggest responding to the [answer](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1701/935) on my question there, and ask if there's even an interest in them migrating existing and/or new questions to our site.

If so, then we can discuss which, if any, we want to receive, and then the mods of the two sites can make those migrations happen.  (I would suggest waiting until we have our Pro-Tem moderators appointed and for this final step, as it makes more sense for them, rather than our CM, to handle those details and negotiations, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Unless those questions were somehow deemed off topic on Linguistics SE, we would really have *no* cause to remove content from another site… and the reputation/ownership that goes with it.

Keep in mind that migrating questions asked elsewhere is far from ideal.  Questions imported from elsewhere would likely be orphaned if the author does not have an account here. The tags wouldn't match. They may not follow the posting guidelines here. And anonymous content always has that odd, back-dated feel of long-forgotten questions that no one really cares about any longer. If someone were to post another answer to one of those old threads, or even ask for a bit of followup, no one would receive the notification as they do now.

Essentially, we would be loading your fresh, new site with a lot of questions asked and answered a long time ago… without imparting any of the benefits of reputation, ownership, or experience into the community that is supposed to take care of it.

That's why **I generally do *not* recommend migrating questions away from another site** as a way to build your content… unless they have somehow become off topic there.

Answer (score 1):

We should ask them to migrate it here. But we must employ great caution. Here is the reason,

Here are some examples of possible questions for migration which are well recieved on that site(examples provided by site moderator in [his answer](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1701) to Flimzy). They consider these questions can be migrated to our site.

1. [Can I learn a new language just by listening or watching videos?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1792/can-i-learn-a-new-language-just-by-listening-or-watching-videos)
2. [Is there a way to learn Icelandic phonetics online?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3924/is-there-a-way-to-learn-icelandic-phonetics-online)
3. [What are the general ways adopted by most people to learn english syntax precisely?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12773/what-are-the-general-ways-adopted-by-most-people-to-learn-english-syntax-precise)

These questions corresponds to a single language. Will such questions be welcomed here if migrated?

If not, then we best ignore them as these questions are well recieved on that site. We should not be migrating such questions and asking the OP to edit these questions as questions like these are accepted by those users.